# zipfile module in python to compress files

Tags: python, python-zipfile

Can zipfile module be used to compress files to a 7z archive? I have to work with a set of csv files and I have been asked to 7zip these files. I wanted to know if zipfile module in python would compress these files to 7z archive.

Answer (score 0):

Zipfile does not compress to 7zip archives. You can write :

```
with ZipFile('archive.7z', 'w'):
```

it will create the archive, no problem, but you cannot decompress it like a .7z, it's still a .zip (structurally) with the wrong extension at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Zipfile does not support the compression method used by default in the 7zip file format, [LZMA](https://www.7-zip.org/7z.html). However, you can use [community provided bindings](https://www.joachim-bauch.de/projects/pylzma/) to compress a file with LZMA. Install the pylzma library to your python environment. Once the module is installed, it is pretty straight forward to compress a file.

```
import pylzma
compressed = pylzma.compress(my_csv.csv)
```

The compressed file should be acceptable for 7zip. [Usage docs](https://pylzma.readthedocs.io/en/latest/USAGE/).